# Update one List<T> from another List<T> when data changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, inotifypropertychanged

I have binded a Listbox with observablecollection and selected Item in my ViewModel.

**XAML:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryLst}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCategory,Mode=TwoWay}"  />
```

**C#: View Model**

```
private List<Category> _CategoryLst = new List<Category>();
private Category _SelectedCategory = new Category();

public List<Category> CategoryLst 
{
    get { return _CategoryLst ; }
    set
    {
        SetPropert(ref _CategoryLst , value);
    }
}

public Category SelectedCategory 
{
    get { return _SelectedCategory  ; }
    set
    {
        SetPropert(ref _SelectedCategory  , value);
    }
}
```

When I receiving new list of data I just need to update the changes so that it reflect the same on the UI. Currently I am just assigning the new data to the List and it updates the entire list on the UI because of OnNotifyPropertyChanged implemented within SetProperty:

**C# View Model**

```
CategoryLst = UpdatedCategoryLst;
```

This causes a flicker on the UI as selected item is also binded on the UI. How can i just update only those element which are updated in the list without causing a flicker due to complete List updation?

Comment: Small code review: `CategoryLst` is a bad name, just name this `Categories`. Also, it is convention for private fields to be camelCase, so `_categories` instead of `_CategoryLst`. (And IMHO starting with an underscore also isn't that great of an idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you mention that you bind the `ComboBox` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` while your ViewModel shows you actually bind to a `List<T>`. Nonetheless, you can prevent flickering by making the collection itself read-only and just update the Categories on a item-per-item basis. For this to work you'll of course need something of a CategoryId to correlate the old items with the updated ones:

```
// Called when updates takes place...
private void OnCategoryListUpdated()
{
    foreach (var updatedCategory in UpdatedCategoryList)
    {
        OnCategoryUpdated(updatedCategory);
    }
}

private void OnCategoryUpdated(Category updatedCategory)
{
    var oldCategoryInList = CategoryList.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == updatedCategory.Id);
    if (oldCategoryInList != null)
    {
        oldCategoryInList.PropertyA = updatedCategory.PropertyA;
        // Etc...
    }
}
```

If categories can also be added or removed, then I suggest you actually use an `ObservableCollecton<T>` so that your `ComboBox` will update itself as necessary and also you need to make sure your `SelectedCategory` remains in the updated collection (or is reset to **null**).

Comment: +1. I would also point out that if you're dealing with big collections if possible do some filtering at the database level and provide only the list of categories that actually changed or at least run the whole process in a background thread (or do both!).